# catching error code of background task

Tags: bash

I have a python script, in my raspberry, that runs in a infinite loop. I want to catch it's exit code in case it stops. I made a script named **run** like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/bin/script.py &
wait $! && echo "script exited with code $?" >> ~/bin/log/script.log &
```

but when I run it i get the following error:

```
~/bin/run: line 3: wait: pid 2728 is not a child of this shell
```

Can anyone give me some hint of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried "wait %1"?

Comment: Why are you putting the `wait`/`echo` in the background?

Comment: I want the run script to be free to start anoter script

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing your (single) script to the background and then do a blocking wait. I think, this is unnecessary. You may just write:

```
!/bin/bash
~/bin/script.py
echo "script exited with code $?" >> ~/bin/log/script.log
```